# Using Ansible to enable logs AWS Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, ansible-2.x

- name: Add HTTP listener rules
  elb_application_lb:
  state: present
  name: "{{ albinfo.load_balancer_name }}"
  subnets:
  - "{{ albinfo.availability_zones[0].subnet_id }}"
  - "{{ albinfo.availability_zones[1].subnet_id }}"
  - "{{ albinfo.availability_zones[2].subnet_id }}"
  security_groups:
  - "{{ albinfo.security_groups[0] }}"
  listeners:
  - Protocol: HTTP
  Port: 80
  DefaultActions:
  - Type: forward
  TargetGroupName: default
  Rules:
  - Conditions:
  - Field: host-header
  Values: "{{ item.url }}"
  Priority: "{{ item.priority }}"
  Actions:
  - TargetGroupName: "{{ item.name }}"
  Type: forward
  purge_listeners: no
  with_items: "{{ regions }}"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Pankaj Ambilduke welcome to SO. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69660003/edit) and fix the formatting, since yaml is very whitespace sensitive and your question is hard to read. You will also want to clarify what is currently happening versus what you wish was happening, since we're not at your computer to know. Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page in order to get the most value out of your SO experience. Good luck